# What does this mean & what impact does it have: Failed to download repository information

Tags: apt, software-center, ppa

Today out of the clear blue I received the following message when I ran my updater under Ubuntu 13.10 laptop. `Failed to download repository information`. I see there are a ton of questions regarding this issue but this is not a duplicate because this is just more of an over view that I am looking for. So I did `apt-get update` and started seeing a bunch of 404 errors. I am far from a Linux pro, so how do I read these errors and how can I tell if these are important? I can tell you I have never manually modified the source list directly. And if these are dead ppa sources how can I remove and what does the letter mean in the below, almost looks like a drive letter but I dont have a W: drive.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/saucy/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: This has already been explained in other questions and answers.

Comment: Also about the letters, "W" means *Warning* and "E" means *Error*, this has nothing to do with drive names ;)

Comment: The ppa mentioned does not currently seem support `saucy` 13.10 - http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu/dists/ - or any release after 10.10 `maverick`...

Answer (score 0):

Generally it means that this repository is offline or does not exist anymore.
You can remove it in software center, just click Edit in top bar and then in Software Sources, a new window should appear. In the new window go to the 2nd tab, then select and remove the pmcenery repository.